# Redirect to a remote URL with a POST verb and form data in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-3

I currently have a small HTML form for a third party payment service, which comprises a flashy submit button and some hidden fields.  These hidden field values are specific to the payment service, but the I wish to display the submit button as just one of many payment service options on a view based on a base class payment model, so I don't want to have specifics in my base payment model.  Ideally I would like the submit button to call into an action in a service specific controller, and this action will gather service specific data, and submit a post request to the service's remote site, just as if I had clicked the submit button on the html form for that service.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the form to be posted from the user's browser, you're going to have to use some client-side script either on a timer or on the Ready() event.

Can you do it server-side using HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Is it an answer or a question?

Comment: First paragraph is an answer. Second is phrased as a question, admittedly, but hopefully leads the OP to consider an alternative solution.

Comment: I can't do it with just HttpWebRequest because I need to 'physically' post to the remote page, and stay on the remote page for the subscriber to log in or register.

Comment: It's not unlike the way that ADFS works when authenticating users, with what I like to call the 'ADFS Shuffle'. You render a view with a form containing hidden fields, populated from your model. The URL of the form is that of the remote page. A Javascript event then submits the form. As far as the remote site is concerned, it appears no different to the user having submitted the form themselves.

Answer (score 0):

i doubt that we can post data when redirecting. However what you want to achieve may be done using WebClient object from System.Net namespace. Not sure if it solves your problem but you can instantiate and call it like

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.UploadString("http://www.xyz.com", "post", "a=b&c=d");
```